# Page scroll lag on Safari URL Bar resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, safari

I'm terribly troubling with this issue for days.

You can see here http://www.mobiroloshop.com/venus

If you try to scroll (i've used safari and chrome on iOS) as the url bar resize (enter fullscreen mode), a terrible lag afflicts my page.

A lot of investigation and I found out that this is related to the image carousel (fotorama jquery plug-in is the default magento slider).

Please let me know if you have any solution for this bug (I already tried a lot)!

Comment: How did you remedy this?  I’ve got some other similar issue as well.